# How to check if given type of template function was created?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, type-traits

I would like to detect cycles in class dependency by trying to check if given function was create.

```
template < class PA, class CH>
void dependsOn( PA* , CH* )
{
    #pragma message("COMPILE: " __FUNCSIG__)
    static_assert(!std::is_function< decltype(dependsOn<PA, CH>) >::value,"Cycle in dependencies");
}
```

Each class will call that template function 
    class B();

```
class A{
    B b;
public:
    A(){ dependsOn(this, &b);}
}
```

However this check is not working as is_function returns always true, no matter if such template function was created or not.

Comment: This is not how it works. Type traits doesn't help you in checking whether an instance of the template class/function was created or not.

Comment: Why do you even need to detect cycles in class dependencies in the first place? Even if you want to do this for whatever reason it would be simpler to extract type information somehow (for example by configuring build to output Browse Information (.bsc) file) and detect cycles in type graph.

Comment: @Arunmu You are right. I'm looking another why to detect cycles in dependencies.

Comment: @dodo951 There is list of components. Those components may use each other. Calling stop should be from child o parents. However dependencies are changing in development and cycles should be detected.